# Surface pro 2 Secure boot help

Tags: boot, dual-boot, secure-boot, refind, surface

I've spent 3 days trying to get secure boot enabled with Microsoft keys. So I don't have to deal with the red boot screen and to be more secure. I have tried `grub` with shim and `refind` with shim. But currently I have been working on `refind` with preloader. I think it's the best option since it's singed by Microsoft. So it should work with the surface default key, so I don't always have to have a red boot screen.  However no matter what I try I end up having the invalid boot screen come up and it boots into windows. If its off though I get `refind` with my signed boot options.

I install with

```
sudo bash refindinstall --localkeys ---preloader  preloader.efi
sudo sbsign --key /etc/refind.d/keys/refind_local.key --cert /etc/refind.d/keys/refind_local.crt --output /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-38-generic.signed /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-38-generic
```

When I boot the sub menu I can get to the hash tool. But when I pick the `refind` cert it says invalid and it doesn't auto boot to the hash tool. I have to pick it from the sub menu.

```
user@Surface-Pro-2 ~ $ efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0002
Timeout: 2 seconds
BootOrder: 0002
Boot0000* USB Drive    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1d,0x0)/USB(1,0)/USB(2,0)/USB(4,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x123,0x3f,0x3983bc)..BO
Boot0001* Windows Boot Manager    HD(2,GPT,e61d6d85-9380-4658-ba47-5f533fee3ed8,0xfa000,0x32000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...a............. ...
Boot0002* rEFInd Boot Manager    HD(2,GPT,e61d6d85-9380-4658-ba47-5f533fee3ed8,0xfa000,0x32000)/File(\EFI\refind\PreLoader.efi)
Boot0003* rEFInd Boot Manager    HD(2,GPT,e61d6d85-9380-4658-ba47-5f533fee3ed8,0xfa000,0x32000)/File(\EFI\refind\shim.efi)
Boot0004* ubuntu    HD(2,GPT,e61d6d85-9380-4658-ba47-5f533fee3ed8,0xfa000,0x32000)/File(\EFI\Ubuntu\grubx64.efi)
```

Please help me get `refind` working with preloader so I can boot with secure boot on.

Thank You

Comment: Can yoiu try boot-repair ? If it fails can you post the url it gives. On some "bios" you need to select which OS to boot. and finally , what red screen ?

Comment: @Panther Some UEFIs do present a warning "secure boot disabled" (or something along those lines) in POST. Just a warning, nothing to worry about, and there's really nothing to gain from enabling it just to remove that message. But users tried stranger things before... (no, not the TV show).

Comment: OK, thanks. I try to leave secure boot enabled if I can, silly I know. Not seen a red screen.